# вывод системного времени в переменную

Tags: c++, qt

мне нужно получить системное время и заключить её в переменную искал в интернете но ничего не нашёл.

Comment: _искал в интернете но ничего не нашёл_ - ... https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#currentDateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте документацию по QDate,QTime,QDateTime

```
QTime t = QTime::currentTime(); // переменная типа Время
QString t2 = t.toString(); // в строку
QString t3 = t.toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz+t"); // в строку с заданным форматом
```

Comment: огромное спасибо